# Is zero dipole moment possible in a square pyramidal complex?

Tags: coordination-compounds

Say, the complex is [ML5] and is repelled in magnetic field. Given, its dipole moment is zero. Can its shape be predicted as trigonal pyramidal by the given information or square pyramidal structure may also fullfill them?

Comment: These are two different unrelated questions that are only held together by the fact that both concern pentacoordinated species.

Comment: It appears that you have created two accounts, you can find more information in the [help centre](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) about merging them.

Answer (score 4):

A square pyridimal structure can have a dipole moment of zero, e.g. a squarepyramidal cluster of atoms of the same element would have no dipole moment. However for most cases where the bonds are polarized, the dipole moments will not cancel as they would for other symmetries (e.g. tetrahedron). So basically, most square pyramidal complexes with polarized bonds will have a net dipole.

If you have a complex in mind just calculate the dipole computationally or look at the ir spectrum.